# servicestack twitter auth on azure

Tags: azure, twitter, servicestack, servicestack-auth

I have a working app on my local machine that authorizes fine using both SQl and raven auth plugin.

when I try to test auth on the azure app by going to /auth/twitter I just end up in an authentication loop.

this is the exact same code (except for the callback and redirect url is pointed to the azure app)

Should this work o Azure? Is there any way of knowing why the redirect ends up in a loop? Is there any debugging output on twitter?

Comment: Try to watch the traffic using Fiddler. Look at the response from twitter - maybe it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: I think the callback to the hook happens on twitters servers so I don't see what happens or what goes wrong

Comment: Ah, that's right. I had a little trouble with the facebook provider a while back. I had to step through the service stack code to find out that ss was not handling an error callback correctly.

Comment: AHA - do you have any more info? I'm talking with the guys now to try and resolve it